# how to manipulate my dataframe in spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have an nested json rdd stream comming in from a kafka topic. 
the data looks like this:

```
{ 
   "time":"sometext1","host":"somehost1","event":
   {"category":"sometext2","computerName":"somecomputer1"}
}
```

I turned this into a dataframe and the schema looks like

```
root
 |-- event: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- computerName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- host: string (nullable = true)
```

Im trying to save it to a hive table on hdfs with a schema like this

```
category:string
computerName:string
time:string
host:string
```

This is my first time working with spark and scala. I would appretiate if someone could help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// Creating Rdd    
val vals = sc.parallelize(
  """{"time":"sometext1","host":"somehost1","event":  {"category":"sometext2","computerName":"somecomputer1"}}""" ::
    Nil)

// Creating Schema   
val schema = (new StructType)
  .add("time", StringType)
  .add("host", StringType)
  .add("event", (new StructType)
    .add("category", StringType)
    .add("computerName", StringType))

import sqlContext.implicits._
val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(vals)
```

**jsonDF.printSchema**

```
root
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- host: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- computerName: string (nullable = true)

// selecting columns
val df = jsonDF.select($"event.*",$"time",
  $"host")
```

**df.printSchema**

```
root
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- computerName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- host: string (nullable = true)
```

**df.show**

```
+---------+-------------+---------+---------+
| category| computerName|     time|     host|
+---------+-------------+---------+---------+
|sometext2|somecomputer1|sometext1|somehost1|
+---------+-------------+---------+---------+
```